# Query that'll identify returning active users in span of week

Tags: sql, data-manipulation

Write a query that'll identify returning active users. A returning active user is a user that has made a second purchase **within 7 days of their first purchase.**

```
id  u_id item   created_at  revenue
1   109 milk    3/3/2020 0:00   123
2   139 biscuit 3/18/2020 0:00  421
3   120 milk    3/18/2020 0:00  176
4   108 banana  3/18/2020 0:00  862
5   130 milk    3/28/2020 0:00  333
6   103 bread   3/29/2020 0:00  862
7   122 banana  3/7/2020 0:00   952
8   125 bread   3/13/2020 0:00  317
9   139 bread   3/23/2020 0:00  929
10  141 banana  3/17/2020 0:00  812
11  116 bread   3/31/2020 0:00  226
12  128 bread   3/4/2020 0:00   112
13  146 biscuit 3/4/2020 0:00   362
14  119 banana  3/28/2020 0:00  127
```

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? We need both anyway. And also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: this is a sample data , expected out put is just user_ids which meet the given condition

Comment: Which is what user_ids?

Comment: user_ids(u_id) who are returning customers within a week .

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions to get the earliest creation date and then look for other records within one week:

```
select distinct u_id
from (select t.*,
             min(created_at) over (partition by u_id) as min_created_at
      from t
     ) t
where created_at > min_created_at and
      created_at < min_created_at + interval 7 day;
```

Comment: why not use Between?

Comment: @montelof . . . `between` is inclusive and would require additional logic.

Comment: thank you @gordon-linoff I understood after I made my own example.

Answer (score 0):

If you just check the first time the customer purchased, and a second visit in the next 7 days, you will discard a third purchase after the second visit.
just globally check two purchases in a 7 day interval like this:

```
create table t(id integer, u_id integer, item varchar(100),created_at date,revenue float);
    
 insert into t 
 values (1,   109, "milk" ,  STR_TO_DATE("3/3/2020", '%m/%d/%Y') ,   123)
 , (2,139,"biscuit",STR_TO_DATE("3/18/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),421)
 , (3,120,"milk",STR_TO_DATE("3/18/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),176)
 , (4,108,"banana",STR_TO_DATE("3/18/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),862)
 , (5,130,"milk",STR_TO_DATE("3/28/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),333)
 , (6,103,"bread",STR_TO_DATE("3/29/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),862)
 , (7,122,"banana",STR_TO_DATE("3/7/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),952)
 , (8,125,"bread",STR_TO_DATE("3/13/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),317)
 , (9,139,"bread",STR_TO_DATE("3/23/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),929)
 , (10,141,"banana",STR_TO_DATE("3/17/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),812)
 , (11,116,"bread",STR_TO_DATE("3/31/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),226)
 , (12,128,"bread",STR_TO_DATE("3/4/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),112)
 , (13,146,"biscuit",STR_TO_DATE("3/4/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),362)
 , (14,119,"banana",STR_TO_DATE("3/28/2020", '%m/%d/%Y'),127);

select * from t as t1 where exists (select * from t as t2 where t1.u_id = t2.u_id and t1.created_at - t2.created_at > 0 and  t1.created_at - t2.created_at <= 7  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The above example solved using window functions. You need to use date casting at the where condition since the given table in datetime format. This is tricky part to handle.

```
create table public.purchase_history(
id int,
userid int,
item varchar,
created_at datetime,
revenue int);
Insert into public.purchase_history values
(1,   109, 'milk' ,'03/03/2020' ,   123)
, (2,139,'biscuit','03/18/2020',421)
 , (3,120,'milk','03/18/2020',176)
 , (4,108,'banana','03/18/2020',862)
 , (5,130,'milk','03/28/2020',333)
 , (6,103,'bread','03/29/2020',862)
 , (7,122,'banana','03/07/2020',952)
 , (8,125,'bread','03/13/2020',317)
 , (9,139,'bread','03/23/2020',929)
 , (10,141,'banana','03/17/2020',812)
 , (11,116,'bread','03/31/2020',226)
 , (12,128,'bread','03/04/2020',112)
 , (13,146,'biscuit','03/04/2020',362)
 , (14,119,'banana','03/28/2020',127)
 , (15,120,'milk','03/28/2020',186);
 select distinct userid
 FROM
 (select 
 id,
 userid,
 created_at,
 coalesce(lead(created_at)over(partition by userid order by created_at),'9999-12-31') as next_purchase
 from 
 public.purchase_history order by userid)repeated
 where (repeated.next_purchase::date-repeated.created_at::date)<=7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the tables name is amazon_transactions

```
  SELECT distinct a.user_id FROM amazon_transactions a 
          JOIN amazon_transactions b
           ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
               WHERE a.id <>b.id
                 AND a.created_at <= b.created_at
                 AND b.created_at <= a.created_at+7
               ORDER BY a.user_id
```